# case senstive search with realtime database and recylcerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, search, android-recyclerview

```
private void processsearch(String s)
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Calories> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Calories>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food").orderByChild("Name").startAt(s).endAt(s+"\uf8ff"), Calories.class)
                        .build();

        adapter=new myadapter(options);
        adapter.startListening();
        recview.setAdapter(adapter);
        

    }
```

how can I make this search method case insensitive?
I've tried doing

```
String n="Name";
n.equalsIgnoreCase()
```

; then replaced the word name in orderbychild with n but it didn't work
I've also tried `toLowerCase` on n, I can't seem to find the method `.equalsIgnoreCase()` inside the recylcerOptions that's why i tried to do it on the outside

Answer (score 1):

When you store your strings in your database, you should use a method to make it all lower case, such as `string.toLowerCase()`.

And when you query, you convert your query to lower case as well `query.toLowerCase()`

there are other factors to consider such as special characters that should be removed/ignored but that is out of the scope of this question.